# XPath expression does not work while combining

Tags: c#, csv, xpath, expression

am having a problem when combining in xpath expression :

here is my xml:

```
<m:properties xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">
<d:Guid>fizeofnpj-dzeifjzenf-ezfizef</d:Guid>
<d:ObjectId>6000009251</d:ObjectId>
<d:ProcessType>ZMIN</d:ProcessType>
<d:ProcessTypeTxt>Incident</d:ProcessTypeTxt>
<d:Description>Test 2</d:Description>
<d:IntroText>Incident (IT Service Management)</d:IntroText>
<d:CreatedAtDateFormatted>08.05.18</d:CreatedAtDateFormatted>
<d:ChangedAtDateFormatted>08.05.18</d:ChangedAtDateFormatted>
<d:PostingDate>2018-05-08T00:00:00</d:PostingDate>
<d:ChangedAtDate>2018-05-08T00:00:00</d:ChangedAtDate>
<d:Priority>2</d:Priority>
<d:PriorityTxt>2: High</d:PriorityTxt>
<d:PriorityState>None</d:PriorityState>
<d:Concatstatuser>New</d:Concatstatuser>
<d:ActionRequired>false</d:ActionRequired>
<d:StillOpen>true</d:StillOpen>
<d:Icon />
<d:SoldToPartyName />
<d:ServiceTeamName />
<d:PersonRespName />
<d:CategoryTxt>Change - Interface - Evolutive Maintenance</d:CategoryTxt>
<d:ConfigItemTxt />
<d:SAPComponent>BC-BCS-VAS</d:SAPComponent>
```

am trying to acquire specific tag names values such as

- d:Guid
- d:ProcessType
- d:Description

My problem is that in my c# code this works:

```
 string xml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(startupPath);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        var nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
        //register mapping of prefix to namespace uri 
        nsManager.AddNamespace("m", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata");
        nsManager.AddNamespace("d", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices");




        using (var node = ChoXmlReader.LoadText(xml)
          .WithXPath("//entry/content/m:properties/d:Guid")
          .WithXmlNamespaceManager(nsManager)
          )

        {
            using (var w = new ChoCSVWriter(sb).WithFirstLineHeader())
            {
                w.Write(node);
            }
        }


        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(resultsPath);

        Console.WriteLine("csv" + sb.ToString());
        sw.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

        sw.Close();
```

But when i am using combine it does not return me the values needed altough i used an online tool to validate my xPath expression.

Here is the expression when i use combine:

```
//content/m:properties/d:Guid | //content/m:properties/d:ObjectId
```

Can somebody tell me why is it so ? and what needs to be done to use my expression properly ?

Comment: /m:properties/d:Guid | /m:properties/d:ObjectId

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like Cinchoo's [home grown XPath parser](https://github.com/Cinchoo/ChoETL/blob/0063533692ba204bb9a35f8ffdf04c8272e46b16/src/ChoETL/Common/ExtensionMethods/ChoXmlNodeEx.cs#L74) doesn't implement any support for this syntax.

What you want is quite trivial to implement just using straight LINQ to XML, though:

```cs
var doc = XDocument.Load(startupPath);

XNamespace d = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"

var elements = doc.Descendants()
    .Where(e => e.Name == d + "Guid" || e.Name == d + "ObjectId");

foreach (var element in elements)
{
    // write to file
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty shocked; claiming that this is XPath is gross misrepresentation. As far as I can see, their API documentation gives no hint that their "XPath" is only a small subset.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can pick selective nodes and write them to CSV file using Cinchoo ETL

```
var nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
//register mapping of prefix to namespace uri 
nsManager.AddNamespace("m", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata");
nsManager.AddNamespace("d", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices");

StringBuilder csv = new StringBuilder();
using (var p = ChoXmlReader.LoadText(xml)
        .WithXPath("//entry/content/m:properties", true)
        .WithXmlNamespaceManager(nsManager)
        .WithField("Guid", xPath: "d:Guid")
        .WithField("ProcessType", xPath: "d:ProcessType")
        .WithField("Description", xPath: "d:Description")
    )
{
    using (var w = new ChoCSVWriter(csv)
        .WithFirstLineHeader()
        .Configure(c => c.UseNestedKeyFormat = false)
        )
        w.Write(p);
}

Console.WriteLine(csv);
```

Sample Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pHzDyE

Comment: Thanks a lot! 

but you do not get the text tho. To retrieve the text you should use this xpath

`using (var p = ChoXmlReader.LoadText(xmlDocument)
              .WithXPath(Utils.GetXpath())
              .WithField("Guid", xPath: "d:Guid/text()")
              .WithField("ProcessType", xPath: "d:ProcessType/text()")
              .WithField("Description", xPath: "d:Description/text()")
            )`